# Get current date of my timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this code that displays different results on my development local machine and my hosted site:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
TimeZoneInfo nzZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time");
litUTC.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " " + js.Serialize(DateTime.UtcNow) + " " + js.Serialize(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, nzZone));
```

On my local machine, it displayed:

21/05/2018 2:15:24 AM "/Date(1526868924867)/" "/Date(1526868924867)/"

However on my hosted site, it displayed:

21/05/2018 2:16:01 a.m. "/Date(1526868961581)/" "/Date(1526930161581)/"

Any ideas why the one on the hosted site became 1526930161581? That's a big gap between the two. As a result this became 22/05/2018 when I converted it back to date format. I converted both of them from UtcNow the same to my current timezone, they should be the same or a couple of seconds different.
Thanks

Comment: Yes I know it can't be the same. But they can't be a day different. A couple of minutes is fine. If you run alert(new Date (1526930161581)) in js fiddle. You will get 22/05/2018. The other one is 21/05/2018.

Comment: Yes the question is valid. It's the same code but the results are different. You are saying it's different cause time moving forward. But it's just too big a gap. Thanks anyway

Comment: How did you come up with 36714? 1526930161581 - 1526868924867? It's not 36714.

Comment: You could try to use  DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() instead of DateTime.UtcNow. You can read the date time utc issue at https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-csharp/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

Check the time-zone on the server running the hosted site. It is not New Zealand Standard Time. The difference is:

> 1526868961581 - 1526930161581 = 61200000 milliseconds (17 hours)

And since New Zealand Standard Time is +12, it looks like the time-zone on the server is -5 which is Eastern Time. So it looks like the server is located in the USA (or Canada).

Note that when `JavaScriptSerializer` serializes dates, it first converts them to UTC. Then it calculates the Unix Epoch milliseconds and puts the result inside `/Date()/`. So don't use `UtcNow` and serialize your dates directly like `js.Serialize(DateTime.Now)`. When you use the milliseconds value in the `new Date()` constructor in JavaScript, it assumes it in UTC and converts it to local time using the time-zone of the browser.

Here is the above description from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb):

> Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX [...] encodes .NET DateTime values as a JSON
>   string, where the content of the string is /Date(ticks)/ and where
>   ticks represents milliseconds since epoch (UTC). So November 29, 1989,
>   4:55:30 AM, in UTC is encoded as "/Date(628318530718)/".

`JavaScriptSerializer` has a some problems, and the `/Date()/` serialization was created by Microsoft and is not a standard. It is recommended to use a library that supports the ISO standard instead (e.g. `Newtonsoft.Json`).